# A linear continuous map $f:E \to F$ is surjective if and only if there is $r>0$ such that $r\mathbb B_F \subseteq \overline{f[\mathbb B_E]}$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, linear-transformations, banach-spaces

I'm trying to prove this interesting result. Could you verify if my proof is fine?

---

Let $f: E \to F$ be a linear continuous function between Banach spaces. We denote the unit open balls by $$\mathbb B_E := \{x\in E \mid |x| <1\} \quad \text{and} \quad \mathbb B_F := \{y\in F \mid |y| <1\}.$$

**Theorem:** $f$ is surjective if and only if there is $r>0$ such that $$r\mathbb B_F \subseteq \overline{f[\mathbb B_E]}.$$

*Remark:* Combining this result with open mapping theorem, we also obtain

**Proposition:** $f$ is surjective if and only if there is $r>0$ such that $$r\mathbb B_F \subseteq f[\mathbb B_E].$$

---

**My attempt:** Assume that $f$ is surjective. By open mapping theorem, there is $r>0$ such that $r\mathbb B_F \subseteq f[\mathbb B_E]$. The claim then follows.

Now we are going to prove the converse. Assume there is $r>0$ such that $4r\mathbb B_F \subseteq \overline{f[\mathbb B_E]}$. It suffices to show that $r \mathbb B_F \subseteq f[\mathbb B_E]$. This is because each $y \in F$ belongs to $r_y \mathbb B_F$ for some $r_y >0$. Then $y \in \frac{r_y}{r} f[\mathbb B_E] =  f \left [ \frac{r_y}{r} \mathbb B_E \right ]$.

Let $y \in F$ such that $|y| < r$. Then there is $x_0 \in \frac{1}{2^2}\mathbb B_E$ such that $|y - f(x_0)| < r/2$. Again, there is $x_1 \in \frac{1}{2^3}\mathbb B_E$ such that $|(y-f(x_0)) - f(x_1)| < r/2^2$. Recursively, there is $x_{n} \in \frac{1}{2^{n+2}}\mathbb B_E$ such that $$\left |\big (y-[f(x_0)+\cdots+f(x_{n-1})] \big ) - f(x_{n}) \right | < \frac{r}{2^{n+1}}.$$

Let $x_n' := x_0 + \cdots x_n$  and $y_n := f(x_n')$. Then $|y-y_n| < r/2^{n+1}$. This implies $y_n \to y$. On the other hand, $$|x'_{n+m} - x'_{n}| \le \sum_{k=n+1}^{n+m} \left | x_k \right | < \sum_{k=n+1}^{n+m} \frac{1}{2^{k+2}} = \frac{1}{2^{n+2}} \left (1 - \frac{1}{2^m} \right ) < \frac{1}{2^{n+2}}.$$

It follows that $(x'_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence and thus there is $x\in E$ such that $x'_n \to x$. We have $$|x_{n}'| \le \sum_{k=0}^{n} \left | x_k \right | < \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{2^{k+2}} = \frac{1}{2} \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \right ) < \frac{1}{2}.$$

This means $|x| = \lim |x'_n| \le 1/2$ and thus $x \in \frac{1}{2} \overline{\mathbb B}_E \subseteq \mathbb B_E$. Clearly, $y = f(x)$. This completes the proof.