# Is there any relationship between the constant $r>0$ and the operator norm $\|T\|$ in the open mapping theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, banach-spaces

We have the well-known [Open Mapping Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4355904/a-linear-continuous-map-fe-to-f-is-surjective-if-and-only-if-there-is-r0), i.e.,

> Let $T: E \to F$ be a linear continuous function between Banach spaces. Then $T$ is surjective if and only if there is $r>0$ such that $r B_F (0, 1) \subseteq T [B_E (0, 1)]$.

Is there any relationship between the constant $r>0$ and the operator norm $\|T\|$ of $T$?

Comment: We have $r\leq \Vert T\Vert$ (immediate from the definition of the operator norm). However, we have no estimate in the other direction (we can pick an operator with the same operator norm but arbitrary small $r$).

Comment: Consider $0<r<1$ $$T:\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})\rightarrow\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N}), (x_n)_n \mapsto ((1-r)^n+r)x_n)_n$$ has operator norm equal to $1$ and $r$ is exactly the parameter $r$ you have (and we can make it as small as we like).

Comment: Or if you want to be more down to earth, the linear map induced on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & r \end{pmatrix}$$ would also give a suitable family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments above, we have $r\leq \Vert T\Vert$. Indeed, by the definition of the operator norm, we have $T(B_E(0,1))\subseteq B_F(0,\Vert T\Vert )=\Vert T\Vert B_F(0,1)$. Thus, $r\leq \Vert T\Vert$.

As mentioned above, we do in general not have a lower bound of $r$ in term of $\Vert T\Vert$. We can consider $E=\mathbb{R}^2=F$ and
$$ T: \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, (x,y)\mapsto (x, ry)$$
for $0<r<1$. Then the operator norm of $T$ equals $1$ and $r$ is exactly the parameter in question (and we can make it arbitrary small).